# Retrieve given member of variadic class by int

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

here is a recursive class definition :

```
template<class... T>
class Mgr2
{

};

template<class T, class... args>
class Mgr2<T, args...>
{
  Container<T> _container;
  Mgr2<args...> _tail;
public:
  Mgr2() { };
};
```

I'd like to implement the following :

```
Mgr2<int, double> mgr;
mgr.get<0>(); // retrieves the Container<int> element
```

How could I do this?

Comment: It might help to show some code that you tried. Also to show some kind of stub for "Container".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you haven't tried anything yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct Container {};

template<class... T>
class Mgr2
{

};

template<class T, class... args>
class Mgr2<T, args...>
{
  Container<T> _container;
  Mgr2<args...> _tail;

  template<int idx>
  auto _get(std::integral_constant<int, idx>) const
    -> decltype(_tail.template get<idx-1>())
  { return _tail.get<idx-1>(); }

  const Container<T> &_get(std::integral_constant<int, 0>) const
  { return _container; }

public:
  Mgr2() { };

  template<int idx>
  auto get() const -> decltype(this->_get(std::integral_constant<int, idx>()))
  { return _get(std::integral_constant<int, idx>()); }

};

int main()
{
  Mgr2<int, double> mgr;
  mgr.get<0>(); // retrieves the Container<int> element
}
```

It is probably a good idea to look at `std::tuple`, though.